# Substring of Scanner Input

Tags: java, substring, java.util.scanner, bluej

How do I get a substring from scanner input?

(Before you comment saying "duplicate" or "look it up", I have. I haven't gotten any answers that apply or are within the range of what I'm currently allowed to utilize in my programming course.)

I'm trying to get the program to accept user input using the scanner class, and then print out a part of the input, but only the tail end. In this example I have the scanner asking for a debit card number and want the input to be printed back as "**** **** **** nnnn" (nnnn being numbers from the scanner input). Here's what I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CyberlifePurchase
{
    public static void main(String[ ] args)
    {
        Scanner payment = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your debit card number: ");
        String cardNumber = in.next();
        System.out.println();   
        String concealedCardNumber = cardNumber.substring(15);

        System.out.println("Card Number: " + "**** **** **** " + concealedCardNumber);
```

When I compile everything there are no compile errors, but when I run the program this is what I get after entering a card number (in nnnn nnnn nnnn nnnn format):

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -11
```

Comment: first do `System.out.println(cardNumber);`to see you complete output. Then do `System.out.println(cardNumber.substring(0, 15));` to see the substring. You will probably find that you are not getting the output you need.

Comment: How many characters of the actual string do you want to output?

Comment: Scanner.next() returns the next **token**, not the next **line**. Tokens are separated by white spaces. Read the javadoc of Scanner.

Comment: `Scanner#next` returns the next word. That is the next group of non-whitespace characters before the next whitespace (sort of; it gets complicated, but don't worry about that for now). So you're only getting the first group of 4 digits. Use `Scanner#nextLine` to get the whole thing.

Comment: Note: you absolutely need to use a debugger, or at the very least print your variables to know what they contain. This is a common mistake, but basic debugging would have allowed you to find the problem by yourself. Using a debugger is simple. Take 10 minutes to learn how to do it, and you'll save days.

Comment: @AlkisMavridis the last four.

Comment: @mypetlion @JB Nizet I tried using `nextLine` instead of `next` and it skipped over user input. It won't let me input a number when `nextLine` is employed.

Comment: @CrimRiminic great. Please see my response below. Additionally to the usage of sc.nextLine(), I would suggest that you do not use a harcoded number in the substring() function, such as 15, but you get really the last 4 by passing myStr.length()-4 As a parameter.

Answer (score 5):

You should use `in.nextLine()` rather than `in.next()`

`next` method in the `Scanner` class uses space as a token and only returns the data before the space, hence you can use `nextLine` method

Answer (score 1):

1. As already mentioned, use `scanner.nextLine()` instead of `scanner.next()`.
2. If you want the last part of the string, it is safer to use something like:
   `originalString.substring(originalString.length()-4)`;

Replace 4 with the actual character count you want to output. It would be also wise to check that the length of the original string is more that the amount you substract (4 in the example above).

Answer (score 0):

Besides fixing your code, if you want to impress your teacher you should add some error checking as well.  This can double as a safeguard against `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.  For example, replace the last two lines of codes with this:

```
if (cardNumber.length() < 19) {
    System.out.println("c'mon...  its like this!! \"nnnn nnnn nnnn nnnn\"");
} else {
    String concealedCardNumber = cardNumber.substring(15);

    System.out.println("Card Number: " + "**** **** **** " + concealedCardNumber);
}
```